# Using nested-loop to save files in multiple folders and sub-folders

Tags: r

My objective is to create individual plots for every subject in my study. First of all subjects are from different study sites. I have already created the folders of the different study sites (Site1 and Site2). Site1 has 2 subjects and Site2 has 1 subject. Each subject has multiple time points (Days). I have also created the sub-folders for each subject under the folder of each study site. In the sub-folders, I will save the different plots for each subject.

Here is what I have done. So I want to make a longitudinal plot. Since I will be making several graphics for each subject, I want the picture names to be as ID_plot1, ID_plot2 and son on. I am showing an exemple including two study sites and only one plot. Actually my data is larger than that.

```
## create variables
Site <- c("Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site2", "Site2")

ID <- c("00184","00184", "00184", "00184", "00274", "00274", "00274", "00274", "00679", "00679")

Days <- c(0,1,7,14,0,1,7,14,1,7)

Burden <- c(0.276160910, 0.169563965, 0.016059574, 0.006127718, 0.147416155, 0.009835100, 0.005489384, 0.010319001, 0.008111097, 0.001718116)

## create the dataset
dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(Site, ID, Days, Burden))

#create folders and sub-folders
req(icesTAF)
for(a in unique(dataset$Site)){
  for (b in unique(dataset$ID[dataset$Site==a])){
mkdir(paste0("../graphic/", a, "/",b))
    }
  }

## nested loop to create save as png file
for (i in unique(dataset$Site)){
  for (j in unique(dataset$ID)){
    png(filename=paste0("../graphic/", i,"/",j, "/", j,"_plot1", ".png"),
        width = 7, 
        height= 5,
        unit ="in",
        res = 400)

    plot(dataset$Days[dataset$ID %in% j][dataset$Site %in% i],
         dataset$Burden[dataset$ID %in% j][dataset$Site %in% i],
         type="b",
         main="Burden Over time", 
         xlab="Time",
         ylab="Burden")

    dev.off()
  }
}
```

But I am getting the error message below:

```
Error in dev.off() : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '../graphic/Site1/00679/00679_plot1.png'
```

My understanding is that R is trying to save the plot of  subject #00679 in a sub-folder with its name in the "Site1" folder, which doesn't in fact exist. Indeed, subject #00679 actually belongs to "Site2". The plots for the two subjects in "Site1" were made and saved properly, but the plot for the subject #00679 in "Site2" was never made. Any help to optimize my code so that it makes and saves individual plots for each subject appropriately in the specific folders and sub-folders will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gregor, That part is already done. As I mentioned in my post, I already created the folders and sub-folders.

Comment: Ah - I see. You're looping over every ID for every site, but every ID isn't present at every site. Instead, change your inner loop to `for(j in unique(dataset[dataset$Site == i, "ID"]))` to only loop over the IDs present in the current site. (Much like you do for the plot data.)

Comment: Btw, `as.data.frame(cbind(Site, ID, Days, Burden))` is a bad way to create a data frame. `cbind` creates a matrix, which converts everything to character class. The `as.data.frame` makes a data frame of the matrix, which converts every column to a `factor`. The simpler `dataset <- data.frame(Site, ID, Days, Burden)` will produce a better result, with no weird conversions.

Comment: And `dataset$Days[dataset$ID %in% j][dataset$Site %in% i]` is weird. Use `&` for "and": `dataset$Days[dataset$ID %in% j & dataset$Site %in% i]`

Comment: Gregor, Done! but it did not work. I am getting the same error message still.

Comment: Thank fo the the comment on as.data.frame. It was just to give you guys an example of my data.

Comment: So, the error you're getting implies the file doesn't exist. Are you **sure** `'../graphic/Site1/00679/` is a valid filepath? Relative to your current working directory? R is telling you there's an issue with that file, and the filepath is the most promising place for that issue to be.

Comment: I have updated my post to show how the folders and sub-folders were created.

Comment: I'm guessing your folder and sub-folder creation doesn't work because you don't use the looping variable `b` in your code. `for (b in unique(dataset$ID))`... `b` is never used again. I'm not familiar with `icesTAF`, but I'm guessing the `mkdir` function isn't vectorized, because its documentation says it uses the base function `dir.create`, and `dir.create` isn't vectorized.

Comment: The real test, of course, would be to look on your computer and see if there is a directory `'../graphic/Site1/00679/`. You assume there is, R says there isn't. I trust R...

Comment: I made changes following the suggestions and it worked:
```for (i in unique(dataset$Site)){
  for(j in unique(dataset$ID[dataset$Site %in% i])){
    png(filename=paste0("../graphic/", i,"/",j, "/", j,"_plot1", ".png"),
        width = 7, 
        height= 5,
        unit ="in",
        res = 400)

    plot(dataset$Days[dataset$ID %in% j & dataset$Site %in% i],
         dataset$Burden[dataset$ID %in% j & dataset$Site %in% i],
   dev.off()
  }
}
```